# NullPointerException for performClick()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to performClick on a button in Fragment. Like in the process below:

1. Click on A in Fragment Navigation Drawer
2. App open up Fragment A
3. When Fragment A launch, it performClick() on a button within its class which will lead to Activity B

I have already tried placing `btnSchedule.performClick();` in OnCreate, OnStart and even in an AsyncTask onPostExecute method.

However it all leads to a nullpointerException as show below:

> 02-25 16:03:13.421 17348-17348/com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                Process: com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512, PID: 17348
>                                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.widget.Button.performClick()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.example.l33902.contactmanagment.FragmentPlanner.onStart(FragmentPlanner.java:106)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2138)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:937)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Below are my codes(Fragment A)(Currently placing `btnSchedule.performClick();` in onStart method):

```
public class FragmentPlanner extends Fragment {

    View root;
    Context context;
    Button btnSchedule;

    public FragmentPlanner() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planner, container, false);
        root = rootView;
        context = rootView.getContext();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Button btnSchedule = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSchedule);
        btnSchedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CalendarMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.to_note, menu);
        MenuItem noteItem;
        noteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_note).setIcon(resizeImage(R.drawable.ic_note_add_white_24dp, 250, 250));
        noteItem.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_note){
            //Do whatever you want to do

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CalendarMain.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private Drawable resizeImage(int resId, int w, int h) {
        Bitmap BitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
        int width = BitmapOrg.getWidth();
        int height = BitmapOrg.getHeight();
        int newWidth = w;
        int newHeight = h;
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        return new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        btnSchedule.performClick();

        }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

This line is wrong:

```
Button btnSchedule = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSchedule);
```

It must be:

```
btnSchedule = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSchedule);
```

because there is a member:

```
Button btnSchedule;
```

When you write:

```
Button btnSchedule = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSchedule);
```

you are declaring a local variable, and not usign the member one.

Answer (score 4):

in `onCreateView` you are redefining the member `btnSchedule` in the local scope hiding the class member which remains not initialized. In onCreateView change

```
Button btnSchedule = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSchedule);
```

with

```
btnSchedule = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSchedule);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify code like this:

```
public class FragmentPlanner extends Fragment {

    View rootView;
    Context context;
    Button btnSchedule;

    public FragmentPlanner() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planner, container, false);
        context = rootView.getContext();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        btnSchedule = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSchedule);
        btnSchedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CalendarMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Hope it helps!!!